# Adding contacts to outlook

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am using outlook rest api and need to add thousands contacts. So I am searching how to add range of contacts except adding each separately. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by accessing batch endpoint in o365. Where you can post contacts as of 20 contacts in one batch.

Check out the details of batch endpoint in o365:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/batch-outlook-rest-requests

Hope this helps.